# Is there a way in RxJava/RxAndroid to let the chain of operators finish even after unsubscribing?

Tags: rx-java, rx-android

Basically I have a chain where I call my API and it returns back a result which I use to update my local database. Finally, after that's done, I have code in my onNext() to update the UI. If the user closes the activity, I need to call unsubscribe but that might mean that my database might not update. Is there a way to ensure that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `doOnNext().publish().autoConnect()`. The `doOnNext` should have the database save logic and the rest makes sure it runs to completion even if the Subscriber unsubscribed.

Comment: but if it is unsubscribed onNext() will never be called right? and wouldn't that mean that doOnNext() won't be called either?

Comment: publish() will make sure it keeps running.

Comment: could you explain what exactly it does? How exactly does the ConnectableObservable work?